# MATLAB : How to keep output values after using return

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I have this code segment:

```
function [S,r1,r2,c1,c2] = xor2imgs(org,templete,Diff)
    while (r+O - 1) <= N
           while (c+P - 1) <= M
               if sum_temp <= sum(sum(sum(org(r:r+O-1,c:c+P-1)))) %cond #1              
                   matrix = org;
                   matrix(r:r+O-1,c:c+P -1) = org(r:r+O-1,c:c+P-1)-templete(1:O,1:P); 
                   mat_sum = sum(sum(sum(matrix)));
                   diff2 = org_sum-mat_sum;               
                   if (mat_sum == diff) && (diff2 > Diff) %cond #2
                       S = org_sum-mat_sum; 
                       r1 = r;
                       r2 = r1+O-1;
                       c1 = c;
                       c2 = c1+P-1;
                       return ; %must return to the original function yet keep the output values 
                   end
               end
           end
        end 
end
```

What should I do to pass the values of [S,r1,r2,c1,c2] to the caller function after using return?
I invoked the function as

```
 [S,r1,r2,c1,c2] = xor2imgs(org,newtemplete,S);
```

in another function but it keeps returning zeros for each output....

Comment: Have you read the documentation? See here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html

Comment: It will not even compile as `r`  and `o` in `while` loop are not defined. Also in second loop `c` and `P` are unknown. So you skipped some important part of code in your example, or you have some big mistakes to correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming all your variables are defined above the while loop...

You ***could*** use multiple [break](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) statements. The reason multiple break statements are needed is because you have nested loops, and one break statement will not suffice. I added a counter variable to your code to change to 1 when you need to break out of the loops:

```
counter = 0;
function [S,r1,r2,c1,c2] = xor2imgs(org,templete,Diff)
    while (r+O - 1) <= N
        while (c+P - 1) <= M
            if sum_temp <= sum(sum(sum(org(r:r+O-1,c:c+P-1)))) %cond #1              
                matrix = org;
                matrix(r:r+O-1,c:c+P -1) = org(r:r+O-1,c:c+P-1)-templete(1:O,1:P); 
                mat_sum = sum(sum(sum(matrix)));
                diff2 = org_sum-mat_sum;               
                if (mat_sum == diff) && (diff2 > Diff) %cond #2
                    S = org_sum-mat_sum; 
                    r1 = r;
                    r2 = r1+O-1;
                    c1 = c;
                    c2 = c1+P-1;
                    counter = 1;
                    break;
                end
            end
        end
        if isequal(counter,1)
            break;
        end
    end 
end
```